# Rendering JSON object in chunks?

Tags: jquery, json, render

I'm pulling hundreds of rows from a database and creating a JSON object then rendering via jQuery. But I'm currently rendering all data objects which slows down the page load. What's the best way to render chuncks of JSON on the fly? Also, would it make sense to append and delete the rendered chuncks as the user scrolls through the rendered display?

Comment: be sure to check out slickgrid: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/

Comment: 1)  What sort of chunks are they? Is it an array of objects, or is it something that's really deeply nested that you have to dig through, programmatically, rather than just in a loop or two?  2) How are you rendering?  Are you just adding `"<li> + object.title + </li>"` or are we talking about something more elaborate?   Two quick semi-answers: a) the answer to the question is ultimately by using deference (think `setTimeout` with chunks of data) -- it's a matter of "how"  b) deleting is okay, but can be slower than not if you do it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you are creating and adding a lot of DOM nodes, you should use **document fragments** ([`document.createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)). Your code may get [a significant performance gain](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom)  from this, if you are avoiding reflows on every data element, but instead bundle 20 of them in a fragment and insert that into the main DOM with one operation.

Without knowing the details, **"lazy inserting"** the data seems to be a good idea. You should parse your JSON object and save it in an array, then monitor the scroll position ([use a timer to avoid event overkill](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/)) and insert more elements from your array if necessary. I think I would try to not delete them but keep what you (expensively) inserted.

Apart from that, please provide some more detail: how do you render and insert the elements, how complex is their markup?

Comment: Great suggestions! I actually have 2 JSON objects that have been returned from a DB- one for "categories" the other for "items." I want to be able to sort and display the data in several ways so this seemed like the best approach. Presently, I'm looping over each category then recursing through the items to find matches and render them. (Other ways of displaying are alphabetically by item and categorically by item sub-type. (Any suggestions on a better way to do this?) Anyway, rendering by category is taking a long time.

Comment: "hundreds of rows" doesn't sound too bad. When you say "rendering by category", do you mean "filter the data, sort it and insert it into the DOM"? As long as you are not touching the DOM, filtering/sorting shouldn't take too long. When you have your data, insert it in bulks. Please show exemplary data and filter/render code.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. Here's what I mean by rendering a category- First, querying the "Categories" table and returning all active rows. Also, querying "Items" table and returning all rows. Lastly, looping over category data and looking for matches in items to display like this... Category 1: item, item item Category-2: item, item, etc.  A hundred categories and several hundred items means huge nested loop that takes long time to execute on client side. Looking for a better way.

Comment: Just an update- I think I've seen where I was jumping the tracks. What I'm attempting to do now is only display the categories first, then, when the user clicks a category, fetching the items from the json object and rendering them (adding to DOM). That way, the page is as small as possible from the start and only grows as the user drives it.

Comment: That is a good way to handle it. However, you should be able to prevent those nested loops. You say "looking for matches in items to display", but that should not be necessary if you somehow associate your items and categories in the database (not knowing your exact data of course). Hope I helped. To say anything else, I guess you would have to show code and data. :)